# How do I measue non linearity of solution of differentional equation?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Is there some well known and useful measures of non-linearity for functions? I know this is rather broad question (more precisely two questions), but I'm stuck with my problem and interested in all answers in hopes it will unlock my thinking process.

Comment: Are you talking about non-linearity of *functions* here, or solutions of non-linear *differential equations*? Note that a differential equation being linear doesn't mean that the solutions are linear functions individually (i.e., linear in $t$), but that the *space* of solutions is a linear subspace (i.e., the sum of two solutions is a solution)

Comment: @fgp Honestly, I want to talk about both.

Comment: Maybe you could take, e.g., the $\mathscr{L}^2$ norm of the first derivative of your solution. Without knowing the application you have in mind, I can't tell if this would be appropriate.

Comment: @Frank I need to estimate period of solution of non linear differential equation (I know it has one from physical considerations). I did some numerical experiments with some class of right hand side of such d.e. from my real world application and I noticed that the more non-linear function feels to me, the longer the period it has.